# Generating lists: javascript function with a multiple conditions

Tags: javascript, ajax, spry

You don't have to be familiar with spry syntax but I'm using SPRY (AJAX widget) and trying to write a function to handle multiple conditions.

```
spry:when="{ds_CurrentRowNumber} == {ds_RowNumber} && {ds_RowNumber} < 4"
```

I'd like to turn this into a function that generates a new ul tag in the same div every 4 li tags like:

```
 <ul spry:repeatchildren="ds1">
   <li spry:if="{ds_RowID} < 4 ">{item}</li>
 </ul>

 <ul spry:repeatchildren="ds1">   
   <li spry:if="{ds_RowID} > 4 && {ds_RowID} < 9  ">{item}</li>
 </ul>
```

What would this function look like? Any is help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is normally done with the Modulus operator (the percentage sign - % - in Javascript).

Modulus returns the "remainder after division" which can tell you exactly when you've hit a new "row".

So (not knowing Spry at all) something like this:  {ds_RowID} % 4 = 0  should tell you when you're at a new row - for example the modulus of row 4 returns 4 % 4 of zero (4 divided into 4 has a remainder of zero).  The modulus of 5 % 4 would be "1" and so forth.

So, basically, when the modulus is zero you'd do your special processing (ending the previous list - if one exists) and starting a new one.

Some psuedo code:

itemsPerRow = 4
Start the first row (

  )
  Loop over all items
     Display current item (
- 
  )
     if currentRow modulus itemsPerRow is zero
     OR
     if currentRow is the Last
        End the row (

)
      if currentRow < totalRows - itemsPerRow
         There's at least one more row to go, start the next row ()
      end if
   end if
End Loop

This might need to be changed a bit if your index starts with zero rather than one, but I hope you get the idea.